# split string into non-overlapping segments

Tags: regex, r, string

I wish to split strings into non-overlapping segments where the endpoints of a segment are numbers within a field of dots.  I can do this using the code below.  However, this code seems to be overly complex and involves nested `for-loops`.  Is there a simpler way, ideally using `regex` in base `R`?

Here is an example and the `desired.result`.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
     my.string   cov1  cov2
     11.......     1     A
     1.1.2.1.1     2     B
     1234.....     3     C
     1...2...3     4     C
     ..3..4...     5     D
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

desired.result <- read.table(text = '
     my.string    cov1     cov2
     11.......      1        A
     1.1......      2        B
     ..1.2....      2        B
     ....2.1..      2        B
     ......1.1      2        B
     12.......      3        C
     .23......      3        C
     ..34.....      3        C
     1...2....      4        C
     ....2...3      4        C
     ..3..4...      5        D
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')


new.data <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(my.data$my.string,'')), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

n.segments <- rowSums(!(new.data[1:ncol(new.data)] == '.')) - 1

my.end.points <- do.call(rbind, gregexpr("[0-9]", my.data$my.string, perl=TRUE))

my.end.point.char <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(my.data$my.string, ""))

my.end.point.char <- t(apply(my.end.point.char, 1, as.numeric))

new.strings <- matrix('.', nrow = sum(n.segments), ncol = max(nchar(my.data$my.string)))

new.cov     <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,  nrow = sum(n.segments), ncol = (ncol(my.data) - 1)))

m <- 1

for(i in 1:nrow(new.data)) {
     for(j in 1:n.segments[i]) {
          for(k in 1:ncol(new.strings)) {

               new.strings[m, my.end.points[i,  j   ] ] <- my.end.point.char[i, my.end.points[i, j   ]]
               new.strings[m, my.end.points[i, (j+1)] ] <- my.end.point.char[i, my.end.points[i,(j+1)]]
               new.cov[m,] <- my.data[i, c(2:ncol(my.data))]

          }
          m <- m + 1
     }
}


my.result <- data.frame(my.string = apply(new.strings, 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = '')), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my.result <- data.frame(my.result, new.cov)
colnames(my.result) <- names(my.data)

all.equal(desired.result, my.result)

# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Tough one....I got it figured out for one row as follows: `s <- '1.1.2.1.1'; 
s <- unlist(strsplit(s, '*')); 
t(apply(combn(which(s != '.'), 2), 2, function(x) {y <- rep('.', 9);  y[x] <- s[x]; y}));` Still need more `apply` family functions. Will look at it tomorrow if someone does not post a better answer.

Comment: Perhaps, depending on your goals, it might be more convenient to have `my.data$mystring` as something like `with(list(gr = gregexpr("[[:digit:]]", my.data$my.string)), Map(function(n, i, x) replace(integer(n), i, as.numeric(x)), nchar(my.data$my.string), gr, regmatches(my.data$my.string, gr)))` or another non-character object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
w <- nchar(my.data$my.string[1L]);
dps <- character(w+1L); dps[1L] <- ''; for (i in seq_len(w)) dps[i+1L] <- paste0(dps[i],'.');
x <- Map(my.data$my.string,gregexpr('[^.]',my.data$my.string),f=function(s,g)
    if (length(g)<3L) s else sapply(seq_len(length(g)-1L),function(gi)
        paste0(dps[g[gi]],substr(s,g[gi],g[gi+1L]),dps[w-g[gi+1L]+1L])
    )
);
res <- transform(my.data[rep(seq_len(nrow(my.data)),sapply(x,length)),],my.string=unlist(x));
res;
##     my.string cov1 cov2
## 1   11.......    1    A
## 2   1.1......    2    B
## 2.1 ..1.2....    2    B
## 2.2 ....2.1..    2    B
## 2.3 ......1.1    2    B
## 3   12.......    3    C
## 3.1 .23......    3    C
## 3.2 ..34.....    3    C
## 4   1...2....    4    C
## 4.1 ....2...3    4    C
## 5   ..3..4...    5    D
```

Note: You can replace the `sapply(x,length)` piece with [`lengths(x)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lengths.html) if you have a recent enough version of R.

---

## Benchmarking

```
library(microbenchmark);

bgoldst <- function(my.data) { w <- nchar(my.data$my.string[1L]); dps <- character(w+1L); dps[1L] <- ''; for (i in seq_len(w)) dps[i+1L] <- paste0(dps[i],'.'); x <- Map(my.data$my.string,gregexpr('[^.]',my.data$my.string),f=function(s,g) if (length(g)<3L) s else sapply(seq_len(length(g)-1L),function(gi) paste0(dps[g[gi]],substr(s,g[gi],g[gi+1L]),dps[w-g[gi+1L]+1L]))); transform(my.data[rep(seq_len(nrow(my.data)),sapply(x,length)),],my.string=unlist(x)); };
rawr <- function(my.data) { f <- function(x, m) { y <- gsub('.', '\\.', x); cs <- attr(m, "capture.start"); cl <- attr(m, "capture.length"); Vectorize(`substr<-`)(y, cs, cl + cs - 1, Vectorize(substr)(x, cs, cl + cs - 1)); }; m <- gregexpr('(?=([0-9][.]*[0-9]))', my.data$my.string, perl = TRUE); strs <- Map(f, my.data$my.string, m); tmp <- `rownames<-`(my.data[rep(1:nrow(my.data), sapply(strs,length)), ], NULL); tmp$my.string <- unlist(strs); tmp; };
carroll <- function(my.data) { strings <- sapply(my.data$my.string, function(x) { stri_match_all_regex(x, "(?=([0-9]{1}\\.*[0-9]{1}))")[[1]][,2]; }); strpos <- lapply(1:length(strings), function(x) { y <- {nchar(sub(perl=T,'^\\.*\\K.*','',my.data$my.string[x]))+c(0, cumsum(nchar(strings[[x]])-1))}; return(y[-length(y)]); }); w <- nchar(my.data$my.string[1L]); output.result <- data.frame(my.string = cbind(unlist(sapply(1:length(strings), function(y) { cbind(sapply(1:length(strings[[y]]), function(x) { leftstr  <- paste0(paste0(rep(".", strpos[[y]][[x]]), collapse=""), strings[[y]][x]); rightstr <- paste0(rep(".", w-nchar(leftstr)), collapse=""); paste0(leftstr, rightstr, collapse=""); })); }))), my.data[unlist(sapply(1:length(strings), function(x) { rep(x, sapply(strings, length)[x]); })), c(2,3)], stringsAsFactors=FALSE); row.names(output.result) <- NULL; output.result; };
```

---

```
## OP's sample input
my.data <- read.table(text = '
     my.string   cov1  cov2
     11.......     1     A
     1.1.2.1.1     2     B
     1234.....     3     C
     1...2...3     4     C
     ..3..4...     5     D
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE);

ex <- bgoldst(my.data);
all.equal(ex,rawr(my.data),check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(ex,carroll(my.data),check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(my.data),rawr(my.data),carroll(my.data));
## Unit: microseconds
##              expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
##  bgoldst(my.data)  422.094  451.816  483.5305  476.6195  503.775  801.421   100
##     rawr(my.data) 1096.502 1160.863 1277.7457 1236.7720 1298.996 3092.785   100
##  carroll(my.data) 1130.287 1176.900 1224.6911 1213.2515 1247.249 1525.437   100
```

---

```
## scale test
set.seed(1L);
NR <- 1e4; NS <- 30L; probDot <- 3/4;
x <- c('.',0:9); probs <- c(probDot,rep((1-probDot)/10,10L)); my.data <- data.frame(my.string=do.call(paste0,as.data.frame(replicate(NS,sample(x,NR,T,probs)))),cov1=sample(seq_len(NR)),cov2=sample(make.unique(rep(LETTERS,len=NR))),stringsAsFactors=F);
repeat { w <- which(sapply(gregexpr('[^.]',my.data$my.string),length)==1L); if (length(w)==0L) break; my.data$my.string[w] <- do.call(paste0,as.data.frame(replicate(NS,sample(x,length(w),T,probs)))); }; ## prevent single-digit strings, which rawr and carroll solutions don't support

ex <- bgoldst(my.data);
all.equal(ex,rawr(my.data),check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(ex,carroll(my.data),check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(my.data),rawr(my.data),carroll(my.data),times=1L);
## Unit: milliseconds
##              expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
##  bgoldst(my.data)    904.887    904.887    904.887    904.887    904.887    904.887     1
##     rawr(my.data)   2736.462   2736.462   2736.462   2736.462   2736.462   2736.462     1
##  carroll(my.data) 108575.001 108575.001 108575.001 108575.001 108575.001 108575.001     1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
     my.string   cov1  cov2
                      11.......     1     A
                      1.1.2.1.1     2     B
                      1234.....     3     C
                      1...2...3     4     C
                      ..3..4...     5     D
                      ', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

f <- function(x, m) {
  if (nchar(gsub('.', '', x, fixed = TRUE)) < 2L) return(x)
  y <- gsub('.', '\\.', x)
  cs <- attr(m, "capture.start")
  cl <- attr(m, "capture.length")
  Vectorize(`substr<-`)(y, cs, cl + cs - 1, Vectorize(substr)(x, cs, cl + cs - 1))
}

m <- gregexpr('(?=([0-9][.]*[0-9]))', my.data$my.string, perl = TRUE)
strs <- Map(f, my.data$my.string, m)

tmp <- `rownames<-`(my.data[rep(1:nrow(my.data), lengths(strs)), ], NULL)
tmp$my.string <- unlist(strs)

#    my.string cov1 cov2
# 1  11.......    1    A
# 2  1.1......    2    B
# 3  ..1.2....    2    B
# 4  ....2.1..    2    B
# 5  ......1.1    2    B
# 6  12.......    3    C
# 7  .23......    3    C
# 8  ..34.....    3    C
# 9  1...2....    4    C
# 10 ....2...3    4    C
# 11 ..3..4...    5    D

identical(tmp, desired.result)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice solution. But if there are strings in the input that have exactly one digit within the field of dots, then this solution currently does not handle that case correctly; it loses the digit. (The OP didn't indicate if this case can ever occur, but for robustness I think it would be good to preserve the digit for these cases.)

Comment: For example, try this random input: `set.seed(3L); NR <- 5L; NS <- 9L; probDot <- 3/4; x <- c('.',0:9); probs <- c(probDot,rep((1-probDot)/10,10L)); my.data <- data.frame(my.string=do.call(paste0,as.data.frame(replicate(NS,sample(x,NR,T,probs)))),cov1=sample(seq_len(NR)),cov2=sample(make.unique(rep(LETTERS,len=NR))),stringsAsFactors=F);`. Your solution currently loses the 7 and 2 in the third and fourth strings.

Comment: @bgoldst thanks, I see your point. I'm sure the regex could be improved and handle all cases, that's above my pay grade, but since this is a special case I just added a line to cover it for now

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option. Not clean, but neither is the problem.

```
library(stringi)

## isolate the strings, allowing overlap via positive lookaheads
strings <- sapply(my.data$my.string, function(x) {
  stri_match_all_regex(x, "(?=([0-9]{1}\\.*[0-9]{1}))")[[1]][,2]
})
```

Identify the offsets at the start of each group.

```
## identify the . offsets
strpos <- lapply(1:length(strings), function(x) {
  y <- {nchar(sub(perl=T,'^\\.*\\K.*','',my.data$my.string[x]))+c(0, cumsum(nchar(strings[[x]])-1))}
  return(y[-length(y)])
})
```

Build up the `data.frame` with only 2 `sapply` loops.

```
## collate the results using sapply
w <- nchar(my.data$my.string[1L]);
output.result <- data.frame(
  my.string = cbind(unlist(sapply(1:length(strings), function(y) { 
    cbind(sapply(1:length(strings[[y]]), function(x) {
      leftstr  <- paste0(paste0(rep(".", strpos[[y]][[x]]), collapse=""), strings[[y]][x])
      rightstr <- paste0(rep(".", w-nchar(leftstr)), collapse="")
      paste0(leftstr, rightstr, collapse="")
    }))
  }))), 
  my.data[unlist(sapply(1:length(strings), function(x) {
    rep(x, sapply(strings, length)[x])
  })), c(2,3)], stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
row.names(output.result) <- NULL
output.result

   my.string cov1 cov2
1  11.......    1    A
2  1.1......    2    B
3  ..1.2....    2    B
4  ....2.1..    2    B
5  ......1.1    2    B
6  12.......    3    C
7  .23......    3    C
8  ..34.....    3    C
9  1...2....    4    C
10 ....2...3    4    C
11 ..3..4...    5    D

identical(desired.result, output.result)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: The last string is incorrect; should be `..3..4...`.

Comment: Good catch, I wasn't sure about the logic of that line and made an assumption. Answer updated.

Comment: Good, the problem is fixed. Although I just found a second problem, which is that you get NA on cases of only a single digit within a string. @rawr's solution also doesn't get this case correctly, and I left a comment about this under his answer as well. Try this input: `set.seed(3L); NR <- 5L; NS <- 9L; probDot <- 3/4; x <- c('.',0:9); probs <- c(probDot,rep((1-probDot)/10,10L)); my.data <- data.frame(my.string=do.call(paste0,as.data.frame(replicate(NS,sample(x,NR,T,probs)))),cov1=sample(seq_len(NR)),cov2=sample(make.unique(rep(LETTERS,len=NR))),stringsAsFactors=F);`.

Comment: OP says "endpoint**s**" so I'd consider a single digit to be out of spec.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a reasonable argument to make. But I would argue it's better to support such a case, since we don't know what kinds of inputs the OP might have to handle in his application. In the world of software, requirements are almost always specified insufficiently, if they're specified at all, and it's in the best interest of everyone to try to write as comprehensive solutions as possible.

Comment: In general; yes. In SO Answers to very specific use cases, not so much. You're welcome to find a more general solution, but I'm not spending any more time type-checking/validating/generalising. This was an interesting problem to tackle and so far hasn't produced a simple answer.

Comment: To be honest, I'd rather it left as it was. Yes, your edit works, and I'll take the change on board as a learning point (thank you), but it's not as tidy as what I had. As for benchmarks, that was never in my considerations for such a small problem (as originally stated) and `cbind` is a horrible waste of resources if optimisation is an issue. I was going for readability over anything else.